# change the apperance of a button on click in Android Activity

Tags: java, android, button, android-activity

I am trying to change the appearance of a button on click, like a toggle.
when I click on it i want its text and color to change but its text just disappears.
here is my code for the btn when its clicked:

```
public void ToggleBuffer(View view) {
    if(this.toggleBufferIsActive){
        this.btn.setText("Start Buffer");
        this.btn.setTextColor(0x0000CD);
        this.btn.invalidate();
        this.toggleBufferIsActive = false;
    }
    else{
        this.btn.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFBBAA00, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        this.btn.setText("Stop Buffer");
        this.btn.setTextColor(0xff0000);
        this.btn.invalidate();
        this.toggleBufferIsActive = true;
    }
}
```

can anyone tell me what im doing wrong here?
many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the format 0xAARRGGBB instead of 0xRRGGBB.

If you use 0xFF0000, it will be read as 0x00FF0000, which is transparent.

Just put 0xFFFF0000 and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

private int START_BUFFER = 0;
private int STOP_BUFFER = 1;

first write btn.setTag(START_BUFFER); after btn initialization

```
public void ToggleBuffer(View view) {
    if(((Button) view).getTag() = 0){
        this.btn.setText("Start Buffer");
        this.btn.setTextColor(0x0000CD);
        ((Button) view).setTag(STOP_BUFFER);
    }
    else{
        this.btn.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFBBAA00, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        this.btn.setText("Stop Buffer");
        this.btn.setTextColor(0xff0000);
       ((Button) view).setTag(START_BUFFER);
    }
}
```